# C#(.NET 4.0) application throws an System.MissingMethodException when one of its reference is upgraded from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, interop, .net-2.0

I have an application which is originally written in .net 4.0. This application refers to an library which was targeted for .net 2.0. Recently, I had to upgrade this library to .net 4.0, without changing any signature of the exposed methods. But upgrading the library to .net 4.0, the exe calling this library throws an exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
```

`'Void InteropSpace.myClass.Table(System.String[,] ByRef, System.String[,])'. at` `ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)`

I checked this method (Table) in the .net 2.0 version of library and .net 4.0 version of the library in ILSpy. The signature of the function has not been changed. I'm slightly annoyed as to why I cannot figure out this weird behavior.

**UPDATE**:
The signature of the exported function in old library (.net 2.0):

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void Table (
        [out] string[, ]& TableControl2,
        string[, ] TableControl
    ) cil managed
```

The signature of the exported function in new library (.net 4.0):

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void Table (
        [out] string[0..., 0...]& TableControl2,
        string[0..., 0...] TableControl
    ) cil managed
```

I'm not entirely convinced this is the reason why it is failing. What is the difference between

```
string[0..., 0...]
```

and

```
string[, ]
```

Comment: Make sure, that assembly you've browsed in ILSpy, and assembly, being loaded at run-time are the same assemblies.

Comment: I did that by attaching a debugger to the exe, checked that it indeed loaded the desired assembly.

Answer (score 0):

it could be that there is a new overload of that method in .net 4. This article may help..

http://www.mikeplate.com/2008/09/26/missingmethodexception-and-waitone/

Comment: The function I am calling in the library is not a system defined function. This function's definition or signature hasn't been changed when it was upgraded from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0. I hope this makes things more clear.